# Arrow rotation angle to visualize relative change

Tags: rotation, data-visualization

I want to indicate the relative change of a quantity visually by displaying a rotated arrow.

I am searching for a function that transforms the quotient of new value divided by old value to a rotation angle.

So something like:

```
quotient => angle
1 => 0° // no change, arrow horizontal '->'
1.1 => 20° //  slightly up
0.9 => -20° // slightly down
1.5 => 45° // plus 50%
0.66 => -45°
2 => 90° // anything above a doubling should just be fully upwards, will be highlighted in red
0.5 => -90°
```

Answer (score -1):

So basically I was asking for a function that passes through the points {1,0},{1.1, 20},{10/11, -20},{3/2, 45},{2/3, -45}, {2, 90}, {0.5, -90}.

There are of course several choices. 
One is to fit a cubic polynomial, which reads `56.1215 x^3 - 256.313 x^2 + 464.825 x - 263.522`, note it is not interpolating the points, just approximating.

Another (better) one is a logarithmic function which reads `126.213 log(x)`. I prefer this solution.

I found these solutions using Wolfram alpha. You can just enter `fit {1,0},{1.1, 20},{10/11, -20},{3/2, 45},{2/3, -45}, {2, 90}, {0.5, -90}` there, and it'll analyze the problem for you and present different soutions.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit+%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1.1%2C+20%7D%2C%7B10%2F11%2C+-20%7D%2C%7B3%2F2%2C+45%7D%2C%7B2%2F3%2C+-45%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+90%7D%2C+%7B0.5%2C+-90%7D